# need help to get started with bugzilla

Tags: windows-7, installation, bug-tracking, bugzilla, software-quality

I have been searching for hours for a tutorial that would clearly explain how to install and start to use bugzilla on windows 7. All tutorials I found didn't help me: links are invalid, uses old versions or tells me to modify file that doesn't exist on my system. Could anyone guide me where to search for more clear step by step information about how to start working with bugzilla? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install is a good description of installing Bugzilla, Apache and MySQL on Win32 platforms.

If you're looking to use IIS instead of Apache this may help
http://lpsolit.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/make-bugzilla-work-with-iis7-easy/

Answer (score 1):

Bugzilla is provided by volunteers, so while it's unfortunate that no one has written an up-to-date document on how to do what you want, it also reflects that there are very few people who are trying to do the same thing.

Your best course of action depends on whether you're willing to pay for support. If you are willing to pay someone to help you, you might consult this list:

http://www.bugzilla.org/support/consulting.html

If you're not willing to pay for support, there are some approaches described here:

http://www.bugzilla.org/support/

You can always create a bug here to report that the available documentation isn't current:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Bugzilla